# JavaScript to check if any one of multiple radio input is selected in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm creating a HTML form with subscribe/unsubscribe options for multiple publications (email). And require a script that will check if radio are selected or not. I've not been able to create the required logic. Thanks for your contribution.

The idea is that a) if someone selects 'unsubscribe' then first name, email fields will be shown for that purpose, b) if 'subscribe' is selected then last name, country will also be shown for that purpose. And if both unsubscribe and subscribe are selected then b) applies. So, it is possible to subscribe-to one publication and unsubscribe-from another in the same form.

It seems that the main thing for the JavaScript is, to check if one or more 'subscribe' is selected and then do something, or if only 'unsubscribe' is checked then do something else.

Here's my test form to get the basic idea working.

```js
    function test(){
     var checked=false;
     var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("select");
     
     for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
      if (elements[i].checked) {
       checked = true;
       alert("Checked");
       console.log("checked", true);
      }
     }
     
     if (!checked) {
      alert("Unchecked");
      console.log("unchecked", true);
     }
     return checked;
    }
```

```html
    <form>
    Set 1 <br>
      <input class="select" type="radio" name="A" id="subscribe1"> subscribe 1 <br>
      <input class="select" type="radio" name="A" id="unsubscribe1"> unsubscribe 1 <br>
      <hr>
    Set 2 <br>
      <input class="select" type="radio" name="B" id="subscribe2"> subscribe 2 <br>
      <input class="select" type="radio" name="B" id="unsubscribe2"> unsubscribe 2 <br>
        <hr>
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
      <button type="button" onClick="test();">Run Test </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This: _I know how to make fields, styles, etc. hide/show/apply_ - replace the alerts with css (maybe classes) that show or hide the fields. You can use `elements[i].classList.toggle('showme')` (there are also `.add()` and `.remove()`) to add/remove CSS classes to match your requirements. You can do it!! :-)

Comment: Thanks @RandyCasburn. The alerts are there in an attempt to check if the script is finding selected radio correctly, for the scenarios. Once I have that working then then I can use your info. I'm going to edit my question as it's misleading.

Comment: So...It looks like ti is working. Can you tell me what isn't?

Comment: Oh..I guess I should tell you the `if(!checked)` will always fail because if not checked, the property doesn't exist. SO...change the second `if` to become an `else` without any test.

Comment: If works to check if any of the 4 radio are selected, but I need it to tell me, for example, if one or more of the 'subscribe' are checked. And assist with the a, b scenarios.

Comment: Got it...check the answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Using the `if/else` construct to determine EACH radio state:

```js
function test() {
  var checked = false;
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("select");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].checked) {
      checked = true;
      alert(elements[i].id + " Checked");
      console.log(elements[i].id, "checked", true);
    } else {
      alert(elements[i].id + " Unchecked");
      console.log(elements[i].id, "unchecked", true);
    }
  }
  return checked;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Set 1 <br>
  <input class="select" type="radio" name="A" id="subscribe1"> subscribe 1 <br>
  <input class="select" type="radio" name="A" id="unsubscribe1"> unsubscribe 1 <br>
  <hr> Set 2 <br>
  <input class="select" type="radio" name="B" id="subscribe2"> subscribe 2 <br>
  <input class="select" type="radio" name="B" id="unsubscribe2"> unsubscribe 2 <br>
  <hr>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  <button type="button" onClick="test();">Run Test </button>
</form>
```

Comment: That is cool! Thank you. I'll explore this in my production form and report back. Cheers.